# Cohort table conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm looking for a way to conditionally format a cohort table in Google Sheets so that the colors will change from red (low values) through yellow (medium values) to green (high values) based on the values in each row. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Also, choosing the "Color scale" option in conditional formatting menu doesn't work because it colors the table based on the values of the full table, not each row individually.
I can use that option only if I apply it to each row individually, but my dataset has thousands of entries so that doesn't work for me.

Example table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gpLMdgfs10Flt-VTtsc68E3Feju2H8UQhnai-R_9b3k/copy

Thanks in advance you guys are the greatest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple script in Apps Script to apply the formatting to every row. It achieves the gradient per row that you want.

### Example:

```js
function applyColorGradientConditionalFormat(min = '#FF0000', mid = '#FF9900', max = '#00FF00') {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  const conditionalFormatRules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  // Build this conditional rule for all rows in sheet
  for (let i = 2; i <= sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
    let range = sheet.getRange('R' + i + 'C2:R' + i + 'C' + lastCol);

    let rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .setRanges([range])
      .setGradientMinpoint(min)
      .setGradientMidpointWithValue(mid, SpreadsheetApp.InterpolationType.PERCENT, '50')
      .setGradientMaxpoint(max)
      .build()
    conditionalFormatRules.push(rule);
  }
  // Apply all conditional rules built to the sheet
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(conditionalFormatRules);
};
// Easy improvements: Create a menu to build all conditional formats manually 
// or setup triggers to do it automatically
```

For your sample sheet this results in the following table:

[image: formatted table]

### Useful documentation:

- [Class ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder)
- [`getConditionalFormatRules()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getconditionalformatrules)

Answer (score 1):

non scripted:

```
=(B2:M2=MAX($B2:$M2))*($B2:$M2<>"")


=(B2:M2=MIN($B2:$M2))*($B2:$M2<>"")
```

[image]